# What allows the implicit conversion from a struct to its reference when calling a method?

Tags: reference, rust, dereference, borrowing

Which rule makes the following code work?

```
struct Dummy(i32);
impl Dummy {
    pub fn borrow(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d = Dummy(1);
    (&d).borrow();
    d.borrow();
}
```

I expect `d.borrow()` won't work as it passes in `self` which doesn't match the method signature `borrow(&self)`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) :

> A method call consists of an expression (the receiver) followed by a
>   single dot, an expression path segment, and a parenthesized
>   expression-list
>
> When looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically
>   dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method.

---

### Note:

Automatic dereference or borrow is only valid for **the receiver**. If there is no expression as receiver it will not work. Compiler will expect the borrowed type.

Example:

```
fn main() {
    let d = Dummy(1);

    let borrowed = Dummy::borrow(d);
}
```

Compiler will show an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:34
   |
12 |     let borrowed = Dummy::borrow(d);
   |                                  ^
   |                                  |
   |                                  expected &Dummy, found struct `Dummy`
   |                                  help: consider borrowing here: `&d`
   |
   = note: expected type `&Dummy`
              found type `Dummy`
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized this is related to auto-dereference.